# It is possible to create an int variable in Python outside class?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Python and I am trying to use Flask to build a simple REST-API. I want to count how many lists are recieved from `post` method. To make it simple, I have this situation:

```
#imports to use Flask and json...

myList = list ()
myInt = int()

class MyResource(Resource):
    def post(self):
        # Reciving JSON and parsing it to a list
        myList = json.loads(recivedJSON)
        myInt += 1
        # other method stuff...
```

While I can use `myList` without a single warning, when I try to increment `myInt`, appears the error:

```
Unresolved refercence 'myInt'
```

I tried to instatiate `myInt` inside `MyResource` and then calling it by `self.myInt`. In order to understand what is going on, I increment `myInt` and then print it.

```
#imports to use Flask and json... 

myList = list ()

class MyResource(Resource):
   myInt = int()

    def post(self):
        # Reciving JSON and parsing it to a list
        myList = json.loads(recivedJSON)
        self.myInt += 1
        print(self.myInt)
        # other method stuff...
```

In this way, the error doesn't show up but every time I invoke the `post` method, the `print` output of `myInt` is 1. It means that `myInt` is always 0 foreach `post` invoking.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: *you probably shouldn't be modifying a global `int` object anyway*

Comment: "It means that myInt is always 0 foreach post invoking." It doesn't, you are shadowing your class variable with an instance variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate `myInt` inside `MyResource` is a good idea but you need to reference it as `MyResource.myInt` and not `self.myInt`.

The reason is that when you do `self.myInt` you actually create a new variable called `myInt` only available for this instance of MyResource class.